# Adams, Sobolev Space: Theorem2.29

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation

Let $J$ be a nonnegative, real-valued function belonging to $C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and having the properties
$1.\quad J(x)=0\quad\text{if} \quad |x|\ge 1$

$2.\quad\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}J(x)\; dx=1$

For example, we may take

$$
J(x)=
\begin{cases}
k\exp[-1/(1-|x|^2)] & \text{if $|x|<1$} \\
0 & \text{if $|x|\ge 1$}
\end{cases}
$$

where $k>0$ is chosen so that the condition $2$ is satisfied. If $\epsilon>0$, the function $J_{\epsilon}=\epsilon^{-n}J(x/\epsilon)$ is nonnegative, belongs to $C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and satisfies

$3.\quad J_{\epsilon}(x)=0\quad\text{if}\quad |x|\ge \epsilon$

$4.\quad \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} J_{\epsilon}(x)\; dx=1$.

$J_{\epsilon}$ is called mollifier and the convolution is

$$J_{\epsilon}\star u(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} J_{\epsilon}(x-y) u(y)\;dy.$$

**Theorem** Let $u$ be a function which is defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and vanisches identically outside $\Omega$.

If $u\in\text{L}^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$ and $\text{supp}(u)\subseteq \Omega$ is compact in $\Omega$, then

$$J_{\epsilon}\star u(x)\in C_0^{\infty}(\Omega),\quad\text{provided}\quad \color{red}{\epsilon<d(\text{supp}(u),\partial\Omega)}$$

Where $J_{\epsilon}$ Is a mollifiers.

> I don't understand where the condition in red comes from. Who could help me? Thanks!

Comment: Can you define $J_\epsilon$ ?

Comment: Is a mollifiers

Comment: Please be more specific about which molifier and how it depends on $\epsilon$. Give the exact condition.

Comment: That condition just means that the mollifier's domain intersects the support of $u$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition in red comes from the definition of convolution and the fact that $u$ is not defined outside $\Omega$. If you were to extend $u$ to be zero outside $\Omega$ you could dispense with this condition.

Comment: The statement of the theorem cited by the OP seems to assume exactly this: $u$ is defined in all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and is zero outside of $\Omega$.  So, I am not sure the OP didn't "cross" the condition from one theorem in the book with another theorem.